# Display keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio context menus

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Most of the time I use Visual Studio 2008. When right-clicking in this product, a context menu appears.

I'd like to see the keyboard shortcuts bound to each menu item in the context menu.

Does anyone know how to display these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to get them in the context menus, but you can get them in the tooltips, as when you hover over an item in a toolbar.

Go to `Tools>Customize` and select the checkbox that says `Show shortcut keys in ScreenTips`.

If you go to `Tools>Options>Keyboard` there is a very handy search feature (`Show commands containing:`), so you can find a specific command (and then set or change the key binding, if desired).

Comment: This is still bogus in more recent VS versions: when you set a keyboard shortcut, it doesn't display in the menus (either main menu or contextual menu). It seems only the default shortcuts are displayed. It's quite surprising to me because that's something good GUI frameworks usually provide for free.

Answer (score 1):

I use the **context menu key** on my windows keyboard (instead of pressing the right mouse button). This way the shortcut-underlines are displayed. Now I can even right-click with the mouse and I see the shortcut-underlines. This 'mode' remains until I change focus to another window and back.

Actually this behaviour is like that for **all** windows applications!

If you want to permanently display the shortcut-underlines for all applications:
In Vista and 7 it's here: **Control Panel > Ease of Access Center > Make the keyboard easier to use > Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys**

Comment: That is handy thanks, although what i'm looking for is keyboard shortcuts bound directly to a command, rather than navigating through a menu.