# Show shortcut keys in ScreenTips in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, tooltip

In Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 you used to be able to mouse over the toolbar and a tooltip would pop up showing the associated shortcut key if you turned on the feature. This feature seems to be missing in VS 2010.

Method to configure this feature in 2005 and 2008: [Display keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio context menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151899/display-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio-context-menus)

Suzanne Hanson from Microsoft indicated in a post that for 2010, this feature would not be configurable and would be turned on by default. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/489554/toolbar-icons-tool-tips-missing-shortcut-hint.

Does anyone have this feature turned on? Could it just be that my Visual Studio Version is out-dated? (Help -> About reports Visual Studio 2010 v. 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel)

Comment: Works on my machine, same version.

Comment: I have the same version Professional and see the shortcuts.

Comment: Strange. Working for me as well - same version. Some other dude having the same problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/ccd2aba9-78df-4550-922b-3ef6b11f6bb5 --> no solution there either. Try starting devenv in safe mode and check your registry like explained in the thread

Comment: I repaired my VS with the same version and I see them now. Not sure how that happened. Thanks to everyone for confirming that they should be there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tooltips are there by default (at least in my version Visual Studio 2010 v. 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel). If you don't see them, try repairing/reinstalling. That fixed it for me.